# What are com.sonyericsson.usbux and com.sonyericsson.capabilities?

Tags: sony-ericsson-xperia-neo

[This list](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1089470&page=3) tells me that I should not remove them, but what do they do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=14772847&postcount=21), `com.sonyericsson.usbux` is `enhancedusbux.apk` app, which handles USB support.

`com.sonyericsson.capabilities` belongs to `DefaultCapabilities.apk` app, but I haven't been able to find anything about its functionality, other than a cryptic "hardware capabilities" description.